# Which protocol to extend for Trie type?

Tags: types, clojure, records, trie

I'm writing an implementation of a Trie data structure in Clojure and figured it would be best to use defrecord to create my own type which can overload the functions which operate on collections. How can I determine the name of the protocol to extend so that I can implement conj and other similar functions for my new Trie type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to implement a new data structure, you'll want to use `deftype` instead of `defrecord`, as the latter hardwires a certain implementation of map behaviour for the resulting types.

As for `clojure.core` collection functions, most of them are based on interfaces rather than protocols. (ClojureScript does use protocols, however.) The simplest way to discover which interfaces may be relevant to a new data structure is to examine similar data structures that already exist:

```
;; all superclasses and interfaces of the class of {}, that is,
;; clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
(ancestors (class {}))

;; interfaces only
(filter #(.isInterface %) (ancestors (class {})))
```

Since you're planning on implementing a trie, I'm guessing you want to implement a map or set. If so, [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) implements all the relevant interfaces (and all the relevant protocols in the ClojureScript version) – you could have a look at the source.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I am having another problem though, how would I determine the name and argument order of the functions to extend? For example, I know `empty?` is part of the set interface, but in the java code it appears as `empty`. Additionally, `cons` takes the sequence as the second argument, but when defining functions in protocols, the argument list expects `this` as the first argument, instead. How do I get around this?

Comment: For `clojure.lang` interfaces, you can look at the source, either of Clojure itself or of a library that implements those interfaces (like the above-mentioned data.avl). For JDK-provided interfaces, it makes more sense to read the Javadoc – [here's the page about java.util.Map in JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), others are easily googleable. It doesn't matter what order the user-facing functions take their arguments in; you need to implement the methods declared in the appropriate interfaces and functions from `clojure.core` will take care of calling them.

Comment: Also, `empty?` does not correspond directly to any method in any built-in interface. Instead, it's built out of `not` and `seq` – see `(source empty?)`. The method `empty` declared by `clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection` corresponds instead to the function `clojure.core/empty` – see `(doc empty)` for a description of what it does.